# Laravel: Unable to find component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Tengo un proyecto laravel donde tengo el componente
CalidadEspesor.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class CalidadEspesor extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public function render()
    {

        $calidadEspesor = DB::table('tipos')
        ->selectRaw('calidad, espesor, sum(peso*stock) as peso')
        ->groupBy('calidad')
        ->groupBy('espesor')
        ->get();

        return view('livewire.calidadEspesor.view', ['calidadEspesor' => $calidadEspesor]);
    }
}
```

en la dirección app/Http/livewire, por otro lado tengo una carpeta en la direccion resources\views\livewire\calidadEspesor donde tengo los siguientes archivos:

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @livewire('calidadEspesor')
        </div>     
    </div>   
</div>
@endsection
```

y junto a este ultimo archivo tengo el archivo view.blade.php el cual retorno con el render del componente calidadEspesor

accedo a esta vista con

```
Route::view('calidadEspesor', 'livewire.calidadEspesor.index')->middleware('auth');
```

El error "Unable to find component: [calidadEspesor]" creo que debe ser un error sencillo de resolver pero no logro verlo y esta forma de utilizar los componentes y vistas me a funcionado hasta ahora. cualquier ayuda sirve, desde ya gracias :)